# Pegar coordenada da imagem ao clicar nela

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

Estou em um projeto Xamarin/Android. Preciso que quando o usuário tocar em cima de uma `ImageView` eu consiga pegar as coordenadas (da imagem) desse toque.

Como fazer isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recentemente passei por um caso parecido, e, se você está realmente querendo as coordenadas da **imagem**, a maneira que você fez não irá funcionar, pois o argumento `e` contém informações do lugar do **`ImageView`** que foi tocado, e não o lugar da **Imagem**.

para exemplificar melhor:

digamos que você tem um aparelho com a resolução de 1920x1080, e um `ImageView` com `width` com valor setado como `match_parent`, e o `src` com uma imagem 1280x720. Caso você toque no canto superior direito da imagem, o `GetX()` retornará 1080 (lugar da tela) e não 720 (lugar da imagem que foi realmente tocado)

Solução: continue usando este método, mas para saber a posição real do toque na **Imagem**, calcule a diferença de tamanho da imagem antes de ser colocada na `ImageView`, e depois de ser colocada.

```
byte[] decodedString = Base64.Decode(ImagemOriginal, Base64Flags.Default);
Bitmap decodedByte = BitmapFactory.DecodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.Length);       
int originalWidth = decodedByte.Width;

ImageView imag = _View.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.img);
imag.SetImageBitmap(decodedByte);
Double fatorDiferenca = (double)imag.MeasuredWidth /(double)originalWidth;
```

então sempre que você quiser pegar a posição na imagem, multiplique o valor obtido pelo `GetX()` por `fatorDiferenca`:

```
var posicaoReal = e.Event.GetX() * fatorDiferenca;
```

(isso vale tanto para X quanto para Y)

Edit: Para poder desenhar algo no lugar que você clicou você deve usar apenas o GetX() e o GetY() normalmente, pois você estará desenhando efetivamente no **`ImageView`** e não na imagem que serviu como resource. Para você desenhar algo dentro do seu `ImageView` receio que você terá que fazer uma classe herdando de `ImageView` para que possa fazer isso:

```
   public class CustomImageView : ImageView
   {
        private int _CurrentX;
        private int _CurrentY;

        public override bool OnTouchEvent(MotionEvent e)
        {
            if (e.Action == MotionEventActions.Up)
            {
                _CurrentX = (int)e.GetX();
                _CurrentY = (int)e.GetY();

                Invalidate();
            }

            return true;
        }

        protected override void OnDraw(Canvas canvas)
        {
            base.OnDraw(canvas);

            using (var paint = new Paint(PaintFlags.AntiAlias))
            {
                paint.Color = Color.Red;

                canvas.DrawCircle(_CurrentX, _CurrentY, 20, paint);    
            }
        }
    }
```

Para que você saiba qual lugar da **imagem** você está clicando, em pixels, você tem que fazer da maneira que eu tinha dito, pegue o GetX() e multiplique pelo fator de diferença, se quiser pode armazenar em uma variável para usos futuros.

Comment: Estou querendo fazer isso inclusive, se tu quiser editar tua resposta pra se adequar a isso (de colocar um pequeno quadrado no lugar do toque) que também estou com dificuldade em criar o atributo

Comment: Não pretendo desenhar na imagem em si, mas sim na posição correspondente ao toque. E ainda nem é um desenho, é jogar um objeto novo naquela posição mesmo

Answer (score 0):

Eu resolvi meu problema fazendo o seguinte:

Primeiro criei uma relação entre o meu `ImageView` e a minha `Activity`:

`private ImageView _myImage;
_myImage = FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.myImage);`

Então criei um evento de toque do meu `ImageView`:

`_myImage.Touch += _myImage_Touch;`

E no método dele, ele pega as coordenadas do toque através do parâmetro `e` acessando o `e.Event.GetX();` e `e.Event.GetY();` Usei também um `if` que verifica se o valor de `e.Event.Action` é igual à `MotionEventActions.Down`. Desse modo, o evento só é executado uma vez, quando o dedo encosta na tela.

O método ficou assim:

```
private void _imgRoute_Touch(object sender, View.TouchEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.Event.Action == MotionEventActions.Down)
    {   
      float x = e.Event.GetX();
      float y = e.Event.GetY();

      //resto do meu código
    }
}
```